# How do I make my command not mention the user?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I just started coding my Discord bot and I made a command that replies to every message that isn’t sent by a bot. When I tried it in DMs it works fine, but when I tried it in my server it would mention the user before the command. In the DM it would say just “test”, but in the server it would say something like “@ExampleUser, test”.

Is there a way I can fix this? Here’s my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.on("message", (message) => {
  if (message.author.bot) return; 
  return message.reply("test") 
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of [`message.reply('test')`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=reply) use [`message.channel.send('test')`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=send) that sends a message to the channel the original message was sent to.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

use `message.channel.send('string');` instead of `.reply()`

Comment: The first one is correct but your method two has nothing to do with the question as using the option `disableMentions: "all"` will still display “@ExampleUser, test” if OP uses the `reply()` method.

Comment: No worries, @EJBEAN ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy :)

Instead of saying `message.reply('message')` you just have to say `message.channel.send('message')`